# Is it true that $\exists a\in I\ \text{and}\ \epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is constant on $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\bigcap I$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning, simple-functions

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a simple function where $I$ is an interval with more than one point. Is it true that $\exists a\in I\ \text{and}\ \epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is constant on $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\bigcap I$? (Here, by a simple function is meant a function with finite range).

I think the answer to the question is YES.  But I cannot find a way to prove this. I tried supposing the negation and tried to obtain a contradiction. Yet I went nowhere with my attempt. Can someone please give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

What do you think about $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}$ ?

Comment: Got it. So the claim is not necessarily true. Thank you.